# Why is abortion such a central issue in US politics, but not in the UK?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, comparative-politics, abortion

In Britain (excl Northern Ireland) a country close in many respects to the US - in terms of religious history, society, status of women, medical ethics etc abortion is rarely a political issue.

The Act of 1967 made it virtually available on demand up to 28 weeks. This was reduced in 1990 by the Human Fertilisation and Embryology Act to 24 weeks, and allowed on the following very wide and encompassing grounds, certified by two doctors:

> Ground A – risk to the life of the pregnant woman; Ground B – to
> prevent grave permanent injury to the physical or mental health of the
> pregnant woman; Ground C – risk of injury to the physical or mental
> health of the pregnant woman (up to 24 weeks in the pregnancy); Ground
> D – risk of injury to the physical or mental health of any existing
> children of the family of the pregnant woman (up to 24 weeks in the
> pregnancy); Ground E – substantial risk that if the child were born it
> would suffer from such physical or mental abnormalities as to be
> seriously handicapped; Ground F – to save the life of the pregnant
> woman; or Ground G – to prevent grave permanent injury to the physical
> or mental health of the pregnant woman in an emergency.[12] **(Wikipedia)**

It has never been a party-political matter, rarely gets into the headlines - except when Northern Ireland is the subject of discussion - and most people, other than a few activists, seem to accept the law as it stands as reasonable.

The political position in the United States could not be more different. There it can decide elections, even the presidency - and it is the key issue determining appointments to the supreme court. It plays a huge part in dividing the population, and individual states, into two rival camps.

A gulf also separates the US from the UK on the matter of gun control - but there the reason is more obvious, given America's history as a frontier society. But quite why the US is so divided on a matter which can intimately affect any family, where it hardly ever enters a panel discussion, let alone an argument in a pub in Britain, is puzzling.

An article in this week's edition of *The Economist* entitled *What happens after Roe?* suggests the following:

> In other countries abortion tends to be embedded in broader health-care systems. In the United States it is practised almost exclusively in stand-alone clinics, largely so that providers can avoid the costly billing systems found in hospitals. Yet this has made the job of anti-abortion campaigners easier, allowing them to find the right women to shout at and enabling them to portray abortion as being separate and different.

Somehow, it seems to me that this cannot provide the whole answer - there has to be a more basic reason.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to debate the question matter. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer. If you would like to discuss, please use the chat function. Please try to limit these comments to suggesting improvements to the question.

Comment: Title says UK but question body says "Britain (excl Northern Ireland)." Please make the title match the question or vice versa.

Comment: I'd dispute that the UK is close to the US in terms of religious history. The US has since its earliest days had significant involvement at all levels by radical Christian fundamentalists (e.g. the Pilgrims), whilst the UK has been dominated by much more moderate groups since the civil war, in large part because of the establish CoE. More recently, levels of religiosity are vastly lower in the UK than in the US (visible in the fact that we've had two openly irreligious PM's, and the rest tend not to speak about their faith much, the exact opposite of what you see in the US)

Comment: Nitpick: Britain is not a country, but a landmass.

Comment: I would argue that the UK is not as exempt from women's rights debates as the opening post makes it seem. Marital rape was legal until 1991, no-fault divorces are only introduced on April 6, 2022, and trans women's rights are still a topic of political debate and public campaigns in 2022.

Comment: @Xano But there is no concerted campaign in Britain to enforce newly-pregnant women to give birth to unwanted children - in quite the way there is in the US.

Answer (score 85):

The following is necessarily a massive oversimplification.

### Religiousness

America is, by and large, [the most religious of the high-GDP countries that aren't Middle Eastern (and heavily Muslim) oil exporting nations](https://www.csmonitor.com/USA/USA-Update/2015/0316/Do-countries-become-less-religious-as-they-get-richer). Compared to most Western European nations especially, the US has a significantly higher number of people who consider themselves highly religious, and a notably smaller proportion of those who identify as non-religious.  In the UK, [some 55% of people say they are not religious](https://yougov.co.uk/topics/lifestyle/articles-reports/2020/12/29/how-religious-are-british-people), with about 34% identifying as Christian.  By contrast, in the US [some 63% of people identify as Christian](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2021/01/14/measuring-religion-in-pew-research-centers-american-trends-panel/), most of them Protestants, and only 28% identify as non-religious.  That's about a 30% swing.  Imagine how much different the UK would be if a quarter of its population swapped over to being heavily religious from non-religious.

As such, religious moralism, especially Protestant Christian moralism, plays a major role in all aspects of American society and politics at large. And Protestant (and Evangelical) Christianity largely sees abortion as one of the gravest sins imaginable (or at least, it seems the gravest one they're willing to get riled up about at the moment).  There's simply no comparable religious undercurrent in the UK.  While there are surely religious people there who take issue with abortion, they do not pose nearly as large of a sector of the voting (and politically vocal) populace.

### Ease of change

Add to this the contrast in "reversibility" on the legality of abortion.  In the UK, all Parliament has to do is pass a new law, requiring simply a majority of MPs, and boom, you can completely alter if something is allowed or not. You can even override court decisions this way, as Parliament is ultimately the supreme authority. Contrast in America, where a right to abortion has thus far [been held as constitutionally protected](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1971/70-18) by our Supreme Court.  And the only thing that can override the Supreme Court on this is itself or a constitutional amendment.

An amendment normally requires congressional two-thirds majorities in both chambers (only one of which is proportionate to population, but gerrymandered) and three quarters of states (which is definitely not proportionate to national population).  This is obscenely difficult, and in theory a rather small fraction of our population can prevent any amendment, even if everyone else is vigorously in favor.  Thus the much simpler solution: alter the Supreme Court to your view point. Which is still hard due to lifetime appointments, but easier than an amendment you don't have massive majorities for these days.  And if you succeed, that difficulty now protects your success. The only way to go about that is through national politics, as Justices are appointed and confirmed through the federal political branches.

All told this created a massive political pressure.  Abortion, once a state issue with little national character, was catapulted into a primary issue of national importance because a significant fraction of the population abhorred the constitutional protection of abortion, and so had to mobilize in the single plausible direction of correction: a massive alteration of national politics aimed to alter the Supreme Court's jurisprudence.  This sort of urgent need to exploit national politics doesn't seem to arise in UK's system because simple majorities in the Commons are all you ever need, and the appointment of judges to their Supreme Court or other courts are significantly less political—at least at present to my understanding, as Prime Ministers are largely required to appoint Justices from candidates selected by an [independent commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_Kingdom#Selection_commission)—, and have a mandatory retirement age.  The strategy of obstructing and playing the waiting game to win over a single government institution to achieve long term changes in the law is much less likely to succeed in the UK than in the US, especially when there are ostensibly much easier avenues to achieve your goals anyway, and they can be much more easily reversed.

Comment: (1) I don't quite understand what you mean about the [appointment of Supreme Court justices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomination_and_confirmation_to_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States). They're nominated by the President and confirmed by a majority vote in the Senate. Obviously there is a whole lot of politics that happens in addition to that, but it's not clear to me what you mean by "confirmed through the federal political branches".

Comment: (2) I've been unable to find any information to suggest that UK judges have term limits. Judges on the UK Supreme Court serve until they reach the age of 75. Judges can be removed by Parliament, though apparently this hasn't happened in nearly 200 years.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff What you described is exactly what I mean by "confirmed through the federal political branches".  Federal judges and justices all come through the filter of the President and the Senate, with no input from the judiciary required (or even experience with courts or the law being formally required at all).

Comment: +1 for some valid points raised. However the article in *The Economist* which I quoted provides a map with those states coloured - 21 of them -  which seem certain to ban abortion, should *Roe v Wade* be overturned. Six more are borderline. That leaves 23 states, including huge ones like Cal, NY and Illinois, where the settled position would not, I am guessing, be much different to the UK. Surely any answer to the question needs to grasp what inclines those states to a position much closer to that across Western Europe - and what is different about the others. Is it simply "religion"?

Comment: @WS2 Nothing is as as simple as "just religion" (probably not even religion itself).  As I said at the start, this is all a vast oversimplification, and there are more factors than I could even pretend to have the knowledge to enumerate that feed these differences.  The division is otherwise probably correlated with partisan divisions: Republican-controlled states, being most strongly associated with religious conservatives and the anti-abortion movement, will gravitate towards banning it; while Democratic-controlled states will gravitate towards permitting it.

Comment: I would recommend changing "Christianity largely sees abortion as one of the gravest sins imaginable" to something more along the lines of "Christianity largely sees abortion as murder".  Sin is something vague that often gets downplayed for various reasons while murder is something anyone can understand why a person would have a problem with it.

Answer (score 50):

In addition to [zibadawa timmy's excellent answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/72734/5534), because abortion in the US is a *stable* [Schelling Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_point_(game_theory)) for both the Left and the Right, because it is an issue on which essentially no actual debate ever takes place.

1. For the Right, this is an issue about the right of living beings to continue to do so, any other considerations are dismissed as subordinate to that.
2. For the Left this is an issue about legislating control of another's body, compounded by the fact that those impacted by the law are exclusively women and the ones making the law are mostly men, and any other considerations are dismissed as subordinate to those.

N.B. how each view *completely dismisses as irrelevant* the concerns of the other. And not even *explicitly*, it's not just that the counterpoints are conceded but de-prioritized, rather each frame *defines* the problem of the other *out of existence*, such concerns are unspeakable, inexpressible.

Since both sides sail right past each other without actually engaging on the other's terms, abortion is a *great* candidate for tribal membership litmus tests: you don't ever have to worry about someone who is otherwise on your side decamping on this issue and you can safely rally your side around it. And this lack of debate is *necessary* because most of the arguments around abortion (on *both* sides) [don't actually hold up well to scrutiny](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/42123/5534), and as one of the other answers mentions positions were more mixed historically.

In the UK it does not serve this function, or serves it less well than other Schelling Points, and since it doesn't automatically mark people as one of us/one of those people we hate, people actually just compromise and move on with life.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135746/discussion-on-answer-by-jared-smith-why-is-abortion-such-a-central-issue-in-us-p).

Comment: "In the UK ...people actually just compromise" Really? It seems abortion in the UK is simply quite legal during a relatively large part of the pregnancy and paid for. Where is the compromise? To me it seems that the "right of living beings to continue to do so" is really subordinate in the UK in that regard.

Comment: While it doesn't rise to the level of a downvote, note that "the right" considers this an issue about *specific* living beings, not an issue about the right to life in general. There are folks who insist that all humans have a right to life, but they are generally not politically aligned along the axis you've described.

Comment: @Corbin that may be a fair point but I was giving pithy summaries of the positions not aiming to capture all the nuances.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm not saying this is the case (I honestly don't know) but political compromise often takes the form of "one side is backing down on $LESS_PRESSING_ISSUE in order to win import concessions about $ISSUE_THEY_CURRENTLY_HOLD_MORE_IMPORTANT". And/or to make an alliance with another party against a third more palatable. IDK, but political issues don't really exist in isolation.

Answer (score 23):

Because when racial segregation failed to cut ice as the banner to get American Evangelicals to vote consistently for one party, they went for abortion instead. Randall Balmer's book *Bad Faith: Race and the Rise of the Religious Right* is a good source on this one; a discussion of it can be found [in this article on Religion News Service.](https://religionnews.com/2021/09/22/randall-balmer-on-why-racism-not-abortion-birthed-the-religious-right)

It's worked stunningly well, to the point that around 80% of white Evangelicals voted for Republican candidates in 2016 and 2020 [(compared with 32% in 1960 and 48% in 1988)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3712056), and over 2/3 of white Evangelicals consider themselves to be pro-life - when in 1971 the Southern Baptist Convention passed a resolution calling for abortion to be made legal in the US. [That resolution can be found here.](https://www.sbc.net/resource-library/resolutions/resolution-on-abortion-2) As you can see, they weren't asking for it to be totally unrestricted - but thought that abortion to protect the emotional or mental health of the mother should be permitted. This is basically exactly the situation of the law in the UK to this day, so the SBC were in favour of abortion laws like the UK's at that stage.

In the UK, the right-wing was able to win elections without focussing on culture war issues, and in fact was consistently in power from 1979 to 1997; by the end of that period the religiosity of the UK electorate had dropped a lot, and the compromise on abortion was well established, both militating against picking it as a key wedge issue.

Comment: `to get American Evangelicals to vote consistently for one party, they went for abortion instead.` Who are "they"? And maybe which party?

Comment: "they" is the "one party", and in the next paragraph the answer identifies it as the Republican part.y

Comment: This answers the question about how the situation arose better than those which explain why the question remains open. Abortion was strategically turned into a political issue in the United States, much like gun control, which some Republicans (such as Reagan) supported earlier in their careers.

Comment: The central tenant of this answer is contradicted by the data. Overall American attitudes towards abortion have not changed significantly since the mid 1970s. [According to Gallup](https://news.gallup.com/poll/1576/abortion.aspx), the percentage of Americans who believe the abortion should be illegal in all cases has been within 3 percentage points of 18% for the entire time since 1975 to the present. A large majority of Americans (80%) _still_ abortion being legal in the cases where it is in the U.K. And a large majority (68%) still oppose it being legal for just any reason, as  in the U.S.

Comment: Indeed, what changes have happened since the mid 1970s have been almost entirely on the other side of the fence from what this answer suggests. In '75, only 22% of Americans believed abortion should be legal in all cases vs. 32% today. 21% believed it should be illegal under all circumstances in 1975 vs. 19% in 2021. While this is a common trope among the left, there really just isn't any truth to it at all.

Comment: @reirab This answer isn't about attitudes towards abortion across all demographics. It's about attitudes to abortion **among American evangelicals**.

Comment: @IanKemp Understood, but it mispresents their views both in the 70s and now. Also, if there were some huge shift in abortion attitudes among American evangelicals, it would show up in the trend among all Americans, at least by a few percent. But it doesn't. At all. The only trend towards an extreme that it shows is on the other side of the fence and even that one has been oscillating somewhat over the decades. In the 70s most, including evangelicals, supported abortion _in limited circumstances_. Those numbers are almost completely unchanged since 1975.

Comment: polls on if people say they personally support things or not don't tell much about what they are going to be single issue voters on.

Comment: @Limer 'they' are specific figures on what became the Religious Right, but I was trying to keep this brief and broad-brush.

Comment: @reirab White Evangelicals used to vote split between the two main US parties. They now vote 80:20 Republican. Abortion is the primary wedge issue which has driven this shift, whether or not it shows up in top-level survey data of all Americans.

Comment: @GuyF-W I wouldn't necessarily agree that it "the primary wedge issue," though I'd certainly agree that it's one among many. This doesn't actually meant that anyone's views on abortion actually changed, though. The change in parties is much more recent, largely just in the last 15-20 years, mostly resulting from the disappearance of moderate Democrats as both parties pushed towards their extremes. Many currently-red states were purple or even blue just 15-20 years ago with pro-life and fiscally moderate if not conservative Democrats representing many districts. That changed around 2008-2010.

Comment: @GuyF-W The change in party alignment isn't because views on abortion changed, but rather because both parties started becoming more dogmatic on their platforms and not allowing much room for disagreement among their rank-and-file, especially those from purple states. The Blue Dogs that were a powerful force in Congress in the 90s all but disappeared between 2008 and 2012, mostly being replaced by Republicans. Not because Americans' views on abortion significantly changed, but because the Democratic party stopped accepting them (along with fiscal conservatism and a number of other things.)

Comment: (And, no, I'm not saying that the Republican Party has been more accepting of moderates in general, just that, on this particular issue, it was Democrats who stopped accepting them in the past couple of decades, especially since the Obama/Pelosi/Reid years.)

Comment: `It's worked stunningly well, to the point that around 80% of white Evangelicals voted for Republican candidates in **recent** elections.` Please, define "recent" (in the answer) to be more specific and concrete. One can still consider 1980s (instead of 2020s) as recent, so defining what you mean by "recent" will improve your answer quite a lot.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 good point, I found a relevant paper and added comparison points in 1960 and 1988. A full time-series is thus far eluding me.

Comment: The anti-abortion movement is not all Evangelicals--Catholics are a large part of it. Interestingly most of the conservative Supreme Court justices are Catholic.

Comment: Abortion seems more important to Democrats than Republicans--80% of Democrats say abortion should be always or mostly legal, where as only 60% of Republicans say it should be always or mostly illegal. ( [Pew Research](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2022/05/06/americas-abortion-quandary/)

Comment: @ttulinsky yes, but Catholics were already anti-abortion, and many Catholics still vote Democratic; white Evangelicals are the reason that abortion is a party-coded, salient issue in US politics.

Answer (score 10):

Note regarding potentially outdated information: This answer reflected the situation at the time at which it was originally written (April 2022.) As of early May 2022, it appears that [the U.S. Supreme Court has decided to overturn Roe v. Wade and related decisions](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/05/02/supreme-court-abortion-draft-opinion-00029473), allowing abortion law in the U.S. to be determined via normal democratic legislative processes again, as was the case prior to the 1973 Roe decision. As such, it appears likely that the situation will change significantly from what is described below over the weeks, months, and years following May 2022, so, while the information here answered the question at the time it was asked, it may no longer reflect the current situation.

June 2022 edit: The Supreme Court has indeed [overturned Roe and Casey](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/21pdf/19-1392_6j37.pdf), so law on this subject will be returning to the arena of normal legislative processes.

Original answer:

---

So, this answer is part frame challenge, but also hopefully an actual answer to your question. Your question seems to suggest that the reasons you list for an abortion being allowed in the U.K. in the quoted section of the question, all of which are related to health of the mother or child, would actually be considered "very wide" in the context of the U.S. However, that is definitely not the case.

It turns out that the reasons you list in the question would not be especially contentious at all in the United States. According to [recent polling from Gallup](https://news.gallup.com/poll/1576/abortion.aspx), 48% of Americans believe that abortion should be legal under limited circumstances and another 32% believe that it should be legal under *all* circumstances, for a total of 80%. Only 19% believe that it should be illegal under all circumstances.

However, the current state of U.S. law is that it *is* legal under virtually all circumstances, due to a series of decisions from the U.S. Supreme Court, the most famous being Roe v. Wade.

Indeed, according to a [study from the Guttmacher Institute](https://www.guttmacher.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/pubs/psrh/full/3711005.pdf) (which is pro-abortion rights and was actually founded as the research arm of Planned Parenthood and named for one of its Presidents,) only about 7% of abortions in the U.S. in 2004 were primarily for reasons that fall into the ones you listed in the question, i.e. health concerns of either the child or the mother. 86% were primarily for economic or social reasons, 6% listed "other" as the primary reason, and less than half a percent each listed primary reasons such as the pregnancy being due to rape, the partner or parents of the mother wanting the abortion, or not wanting others to know about the pregnancy.

So, the reason that it's more contentious is due to the difference in the current state of the law (and the practice,) not an actual significant difference in the overall attitude of the population towards it. Around 80% of Americans agree with the reasons that it's allowed in the U.K. being acceptable, but 68% believe that it should not be allowed in *all* circumstances, as is the current case and practice.

To make matters worse, to put it mildly, it is not at all clear that the cases creating the case law nearly unrestricted Constitutional right to an abortion were rightly decided. The U.S. Constitution says *exactly nothing* about the issue of abortion (unless one takes the view that the unborn child is a 'person' for purposes of Constitutional law, in which case the Constitution *effectively bans* abortion except in cases where the life or health of the mother is threatened, due to the equal protection clause of the 14th Amendment.)

So, we have a case where 68% of the population believes that the state of the law is not what it ought to be and that's completely due to court cases that many believe were not rightly decided. The only way to overturn Supreme Court precedent on the Constitution itself is to either amend the Constitution (which is intentionally very hard to do) or have a new Supreme Court case that overturns the existing jurisprudence. And the only way to get the latter is to have a President and Senate that will appoint Supreme Court justices who might issue such a decision.

Thus, the difference in how central of a political issue abortion has become in the U.S. vs. in the U.K. are not due to particularly large differences in attitude of the populace, but rather with the current state of U.S. law surrounding abortion being quite different from that in the U.K. And the only viable paths to changing it requiring significant political power (either to change the Constitution or to get Supreme Court appointments that might result in the case law being overturned.)

Comment: In the UK, abortion is _de facto_ allowed on demand, although with some degree of hoop jumping.

Comment: In theory, the US allows states to ban abortion after “viability”, unless necessary for the woman's “health”.  However, *Roe v. Wade*'s companion case *Doe v. Bolton*, describes “health” such “that the medical judgment may be exercised in the light of all factors - physical, emotional, psychological, familial, and the woman's age - relevant to the well-being of the patient.”  This can be interpreted to construe *any* reason for abortion as a “health” issue.

Comment: This raises in my mind a question of whether the real difference is the willingness of the courts to get involved. Many abortions in the UK could be challenged as being illegal; but in most cases the courts would refuse to adjudicate such a challenge because the complainant would have to have locus standi. It's not uncommon in the UK for there to be laws that "everyone" breaks without challenge: the 70mph speed limit is another example.

Comment: And if the courts did get involved, it would only be to decide whether an individual abortion was legal or not; it couldn't change the law, because a law passed by Parliament cannot (in general) be overturned by the courts. Perhaps some of the passion in the US is because of the process where it's decided by judges who are appointed politically and then serve for life.

Comment: @MichaelKay It is also the case in the U.S. that charges would normally not be brought for laws that everyone violates and, if they did, those charges would normally be dismissed. In this case, much of the passion is indeed because the issue was decided by courts rather than the normal legislative processes that previously governed the issue. In particular, the problem is that the ruling is perceived to be simply factually incorrect. U.S. Constitutional law is intended to require very broad consensus to change, but the Constitution does not actually address this issue directly at all.

Comment: @MichaelKay Judges aren't _supposed to_ change the law in the U.S., but rather merely ensure that it is applied according to the intent of the law (including according to the intent of laws that might supersede the law being challenged, such as the U.S. Constitution or, in the case of state laws, the state's Constitution or U.S. federal law.) Unfortunately, though, some judges have a very broad view of "interpreting" the law that is more just outright changing it to what they want it to be rather than what it was meant to be. That is widely perceived to be the case with Roe and related cases.

Comment: Even the late Ruth Bader Ginsberg, a major proponent of legal abortion on demand, lamented that *Roe* was too sweeping, and therefore created a backlash that wouldn't have been as strong if the issue had been left up to state legislatures.

Comment: "However, the current state of U.S. law is that it is legal under virtually all circumstances" That is not at all correct. Red states have enacted a slew of restrictions.  "The U.S. Constitution says exactly nothing about the issue of abortion" The Constitution explicitly states liberty is to be protected. Just because it doesn't exhaustively list everything that one might do with that liberty doesn't mean those things aren't protected.

Comment: "unless one takes the view that the unborn child is a 'person'" The 14th seems to exclude them, as it grants citizenship to all born in the US, and even if they are considered persons, that doesn't mean abortion is banned. First, it would seem to only restrict government action, and second, it's debatable whether the mother's freedom should be subordinated.

Comment: @Acccumulation The restrictions in place don't limit the reasons for which one may get an abortion. Elective abortions are explicitly legal throughout per SCOTUS decisions. As for "Constitution explicitly states that liberty is to be protected," it explicitly states _specific liberties_ that must be protected. Abortion isn't among those. As for the 14th, the SCOTUS disagreed with your conclusion in Roe. All 9 justices explicitly agreed that the 14th amendment would ban elective abortion if the unborn children were considered to be "persons" for the purposes of the 14th.

Comment: @MichaelKay Not everyone breaks the 70mph speed limit without challenge - for I have points on a, now very old, driving licence to prove that is not the case!

Comment: You didn't say "for virtually all reasons", you said "circumstances. The Constitution specifically says liberty is to be protected. "nor shall any State deprive any person of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law" It doesn't say no state shall deprive any person of specific liberties, it just says "liberty". And while it's possible that all justices agree that if fetuses were considered persons, there would be no right to abortion, the idea that that would ban abortion is absurd, and I'll need a cite for that. The 14th amendment is not self-executing.

Comment: @Acccumulation Sorry if my meaning was unclear. By 'circumstances,' I meant the circumstances of the pregnancy, i.e. the reason for the abortion. Not necessarily the circumstances surrounding how the procedure itself is done. Limits are allowed there. As for the 4th, 'liberty' there means that you can't be incarcerated without due process, not that you can do anything you want. Clearly, that is not the case and was never intended (nor did plaintiffs in Roe argue that nor courts rule it.)

Comment: @Acccumulation As for the 14th, it requires equal protection under the law for all persons. So, you can't have a statute that protects life (or property, etc., but life is the relevant part here) of one class of persons while not protecting that of another equally. Whether that's black people, female people, unborn people, people born on a Tuesday, etc., state laws must provide equal protection to all persons.

Comment: @Acccumulation As for citation, "If this suggestion of personhood is established, the appellant's case, of course, collapses, for the fetus' right to life would then be guaranteed specifically by the Amendment." - [Majority Opinion, Roe v. Wade, Section IX, subsection A, paragraph 1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/410/113#p86) (In context, "the Amendment" is the 14th Amendment.)

Comment: If there's a law saying that people can abort pregnancies, that's facially neutral law. That this will result in the death of some "persons" and not others is an indirect result.  So it does not automatically follow that such a law violates the 14th. As for your quote, that just says that people would not be able to advance arguments on the basis of a right to abortion, it doesn't say the 14th would be self-executing.

Comment: "Having this child would affect my ability to pay rent" -> "Thinking about having this child is affecting my mental/emotional health" -> "I need an abortion".
Under US counting, this would be 'economic' reasons; under UK counting it would be 'mental health of the mother', but it's the same situation. I think this answer thus fundamentally misunderstands the available data.

Comment: @Acccumulation There are laws against murder in every state. It does follow from the equal protection clause that a murder statute must protect everyone equally, that is, you can't have a murder statue that criminalizes killing some classes of persons, but not others. It's not that the 14th would be self-executing, but rather that existing murder/manslaughter/violation of civil rights under color of law statutes would make it illegal. The quote explicitly says that, if the unborn child is a person, then their "right to life would then be guaranteed specifically by the [14th] Amendment"

Comment: You are simply ignoring my statement "If there's a law saying that people can abort pregnancies, that's facially neutral law." It's not distinguishing between classes of persons, it's distinguishing between circumstances.

Comment: @Acccumulation Unlikely that such a distinction would stand. That would be like exempting certain neighborhoods from murder laws where [insert demographic of choice here] are more likely to live. Clearly an intentional violation of equal protection But, at any rate, irrelevant to the point of the answer and, as mentioned, the Supreme Court apparently disagreed with your assessment.

Answer (score 7):

## Roe v Wade

The central piece here is the US Supreme Court decision called [Roe v. Wade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade) (I'll just call it *Roe* for simplicity). Some other answers have touched on it some without diving into it because it is an incredibly thorny issue in of itself.

*Roe* legalized abortion in the US. More specifically, it declared that a woman has a Constitutional right to seek an abortion and that no state can restrict that right. This wasn't just a fundamental shift in abortion policy, it was a fundamental shift in how SCOTUS operated. Instead of merely declaring the laws were unconstitutional, *Roe* actually crafted policy and legal frameworks where none existed before. Justice Blackmun, who authored the opinion, [recognized this controversy shortly thereafter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade#Harry_Blackmun)

> Justice Blackmun, who authored the Roe decision, subsequently had mixed feelings about his role in the case. During a 1974 television interview, he stated that Roe "will be regarded as one of the worst mistakes in the court's history or one of its great decisions, a turning point."

*Roe* was, more or less, an unfettered victory for abortion proponents. To put it a different way, there was no democratic effort to attempt to craft any sort of compromise that people on both sides could live with. Abortion proponents could expand abortion rights all they wanted (*Roe* only legalized abortion through 24 weeks, or the second trimester), while abortion opponents were left with very little in the way of restricting abortion.

[Planned Parenthood v Casey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_Parenthood_v._Casey) in 1992 would restrict this side further, by creating an "undue burden" standard

> The plurality opinion stated that it was upholding what it called the "essential holding" of Roe. The essential holding consists of three parts: (1) Women have the right to choose to have an abortion prior to viability and to do so without undue interference from the State; (2) the State can restrict the abortion procedure post-viability, so long as the law contains exceptions for pregnancies which endanger the woman's life or health; and (3) the State has legitimate interests from the outset of the pregnancy in protecting the health of the woman and the life of the fetus that may become a child.[10] The plurality asserted that the fundamental right to abortion is grounded in the Due Process Clause of the Fourteenth Amendment, and the plurality reiterated what the Court had said in Eisenstadt v. Baird: "[i]f the right of privacy means anything, it is the right of the individual, married or single, to be free from unwarranted governmental intrusion into matters so fundamentally affecting a person as the decision whether to bear or beget a child."

## The over-emphasis of SCOTUS

Regardless of which side you land on, this has made SCOTUS confirmations more contentious since, politically, SCOTUS overturning *Roe* would be the path of least resistance. As I noted in [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/57427/12027), every SCOTUS nominee since 1987 (except Kennedy) has faced a confirmation hearing question about *Roe*. Since I wrote it [Amy Coney Barrett](https://www.npr.org/sections/live-amy-coney-barrett-supreme-court-confirmation/2020/10/13/923355142/barrett-says-abortion-rights-decision-not-a-super-precedent) and [Ketanji Brown Jackson](https://thehill.com/regulation/court-battles/599203-jackson-says-roe-v-wade-settled-law-that-is-relied-upon/) have continued that trend.

Contrary to some other answers, *Roe* is not settled in any way, shape or form. Polling here is mixed. [Gallup's page](https://news.gallup.com/poll/1576/abortion.aspx) shows that "pro-life" vs "pro-choice" has narrowed to a virtual 50-50 tie and stayed there for roughly around 20 years. Gallup's main page highlights how much more diverse things are with three simple categories (numbers from 2021 May 3-18)

- Legal under any - 32%
- Legal only under certain - 48%
- Illegal in all - 19%

It's fair to say that if *Roe* were vacated, some states would move to make abortion completely illegal within their state (many states have made it explicitly legal and vacating *Roe* would not change that). But the poll above says that position isn't very popular overall. Neither does this give a simple "Should abortion be completely illegal" binary answer. Only slightly more favor unfettered abortion. Most people seem to think there should be some restrictions.

Congress could resolve this if they wanted to. Congress has overturned SCOTUS decisions before (most notably the [Religious Freedom Restoration Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_Freedom_Restoration_Act)).

## Why the UK is different

The UK has two major differences here

1. No filibuster in Parliament. In the US Senate, you need 60 votes to overcome a filibuster. The Republicans (tend to be pro-life) have never had that many Senators at once (post-*Roe*), and the Democrats (tend to be pro-choice) had that many only from 2009-2011. Parliament is a simple majority system of 50% + 1. The UK could change national policy with a popular vote or even a referendum.
2. Better "states' rights" in this regard. The four countries of the UK [have more freedom to set abortion policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abortion_in_the_United_Kingdom) than any US state. Thus the UK keeps the issue local, rather than setting a one-size-fits-all policy like *Roe*

Comment: "Thus the UK keeps the issue local..." Does it? Isn't the legal situation of abortion the same everywhere in the UK and has been since 1967 except for Northern Ireland.

Comment: @Trilarion Which illustrates my point. No state has been free to take the position Northern Ireland had since 1972

Comment: Good answer overall, but it's not really correct that Congress could resolve this by "overturning" Roe, PP v. Casey, etc. Congress can't 'overturn' a SCOTUS decision that a given right exists in the Constitution save by passing a Constitutional amendment. RFRA just mooted Smith by explicitly adding additional restrictions to government action that Smith ruled weren't already included in the Constitution. The other way around cannot happen. Congress cannot pass a law that allows the government to do something that the SCOTUS has determined the Constitution says it can't.

Comment: In light of that, the difference on what would be required to overturn the SCOTUS decision by legislative means vs. to change UK law is even more stark than what your answer suggests. It's not just a matter of getting 60% in the Senate. It would require a Constitutional Amendment which requires a 2/3 supermajority in _both_ houses of Congress _in addition to_ 3/4 of all state legislatures (i.e. 38 of 50) voting to ratify the amendment.

Comment: @reirab Maybe. The catch with that line of thinking is that SCOTUS could make anything a Constitutional issue by simply declaring it one and thus requiring Congress to amend the Constitution with a 2/3 vote to override it. That would mean SCOTUS has the power to amend the Constitution with as little as 5 votes (a strange view considering how hard the enumerated path is). Moreover abortion (or even bodily autonomy) is not an enumerated part of the Constitution. In theory, if Congress vacated the logic behind *Roe* by saying it's not actually in the Constitution, they would also be correct.

Comment: @Machavity Yes, that is indeed the case that SCOTUS can theoretically make anything a Constitutional issue by merely declaring it one. That was indeed exactly what they did with Roe. While I agree that they're not _supposed to_ make up new law and declare it Constitutional, there's nothing really stopping them from doing that beyond simply just making sure that justices aren't appointed who would abuse their power in that way. Which is why the appointment process is so important, especially since the appointments are for life.

Answer (score 2):

Zibadawa timmy rightly [mentions religiousness in his answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/72734/7226). I'd like to add an aspect to that.

The — from a European perspective — outsize influence of religion on public life in the U.S. cannot be emphasized enough. Just remember that religious movements once succeeded in banning alcohol from public life in the U.S.

Such a move — closing down all pubs — seems entirely unimaginable, even ludicrous in the U.K. It would lead to revolution. Wikipedia [reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition#United_Kingdom) (emphasis by me):

> The impotence of legislation in this field [in the U.K.] was demonstrated when the Sale of Beer Act 1854, which restricted Sunday opening hours, had to be repealed, following **widespread rioting.**

The religious sentiment in the U.S., and its emanating into the cultural and political realm, is larger than the superficial similarity of its society and political system to their European counterparts would suggest.

Comment: That was a century ago (and it failed miserably in the U.S., too, leading it to be the only Constitutional amendment to ever be explicitly repealed by another Constitutional amendment just over a decade later.) The religious situation in Europe was quite different then, too, and, indeed, [organizations in the U.K. promoted the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Ribbon_Association) at the time. In both the U.S. and U.K., these movements were heavily tied to the women's suffrage movements. (Also, this seems like more of a comment than an answer to the question asked.)

Comment: @reirab All fringe religious groups. And as I said: "the Sale of Beer Act 1854, which restricted Sunday opening hours, had to be repealed, following widespread rioting..." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition#United_Kingdom) In the U.K. they had a riot because of a *restriction* in *Sunday* opening hours :-)). Just my kind of people.

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is, but UK "licensing hours" (the times when alcohol can be sold) were limited on Sundays through most of the 20th century, without resulting in rioting; in Wales, Sunday opening was banned completely from 1881 to 1961, and in some areas the ban was not lifted until 1996.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the US is more religious than the UK, but there are two big additional differences--abortion was regulated by States in the US, and abortion was legalized by the unelected national Supreme Court overruling the laws of all 50 states.

The UK had one national parliament, elected by the people, that made the decision to legalized abortion. It was the normal, expected place for laws to be made, and reflected a rough national consensus.

(The UK now has 3 regional parliaments for Scotland, Wales, and Northern Ireland, in addition to the national parliament. One of those, NI, did restrict abortion till 2020. Showing that when you divide a country into smaller regions, some are likely to choose different policies).

Some of the US states, including California and New York, had legalized abortion before the Supreme Court decision, and more would have followed, but because of differences between states, some would never have followed. The 20 or 30% who are strongly against abortion in the US are concentrated so they are over 50% in about 1/3 of the states, while they are fewer in the other states.

So legal abortion was imposed on the whole US, from above, not through the democratic process, not reflecting a national consensus, and directly contrary to the desire of voters in a significant number of states.

(I find the Economist's explanation quite improbable--protests at clinics are a small part of the anti-abortion movement, let alone their false characterization of them as mainly harassing pregnant women.).

Comment: In paragraph 3: (1) England does not have its own parliament; the UK Parliament continues to legislate for it (which makes sense, given that England accounts for [84%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countries_of_the_United_Kingdom_by_population) of the UK's population). (2) Abortion was indeed restricted in Northern Ireland - [until 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abortion_in_the_United_Kingdom#Changes_in_law:_2019%E2%80%932020).

Comment: Thank you I corrected the statement about parliaments. Note that the liberalization of NI's law came after considerable intervention from the national government. Left to itself it's not clear to me that NI would have changed it's law, which was called "one of the most restrictive in the world".

Comment: agreed. It was very much imposed from above.

Answer (score -2):

There are already several good answers. There is one more aspect that needs to be mentioned: abortion in the USA is often part of reproductive care that is publicly funded. (for example Planned Parenthood)

Publicly funded healthcare is the norm in the UK (ie NHS) but is highly controversial in the USA.
To put it very bluntly, at least some Americans who oppose abortion resent that 'those women were out partying' while they were 'working and paying taxes'. Contempt for poor people, latinos, blacks may also play a role in this context.

Comment: while maybe not wrong (I can't judge), clearly not complete as an answer: the discussion is not about the payment itself, but whether it should be legal *at all*. That's a very different discussion and is not addressed in this answer

Comment: Factually incorrect - the Hyde amendment has banned federal funding of abortions since 1976.